# Comparing data from two databases

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two databases, in each one a table that holds some data about users. They do not hold identical data, but they do have some identical fields. The bad thing is that these two tables may have references to the same users, but their IDs may not match. That's why I have to compare some fields (e.g. Name, Surname, DOB and Telephone) from both tables, and if all the fields match, I can assume that the records from both tables actually describe the same user.

My question is, in the terms of performance, what is the most effective way to compare the fields from both tables? Should I just compare them like this:

> t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Surname = t2.Surname AND t1.DOB = t2.DOB AND t1.Telephone = t2.Telephone

or should I maybe calculate hash of these fields and then compare the hashes? Or maybe something else?

Comment: What exactly you want to know? Is there a differences at all? Which rows? Or which columns? That plan to do next? Correct? Merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the ideal time to use INTERSECT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

However if you have any duplicate users and want to identify them, stick with an inner join (INTERSECT only returns distinct matches)